# get annotated field variable extra info

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I have a class which has some properties and they are annotated with one custom annotation, and I want its information in another class.

How to create retrieve the annotation instance and how to get its extra info?

My source code:

```
/**custom annotation **/

public @interface Info {
    public String name();
}

/**class where i used custom annotation **/

class ABC {
@Info(name="Institution Name")
    private String Name;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the annotation information at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435036/get-the-annotation-information-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your annotation with retention policy `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` in order to be able to acceed to your annotation on RUNTIME.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Info {
    public String name();
}
```

After that you have to use `this.getClass().getDeclaredField("name")` in order to get your field.You can get your annotation with `getAnnotation(Info.class)` method. You will get an instance of your annotation and you will be able to acceed to its information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-